# How do I setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

When making setState() in onchange and trying to change the value, it writes or deletes only 1 character. What is the problem?

```
enter code here:

  constructor() {
      super();
       this.state = {lw1val:null}
   }

   {this.state.isLw1 ? (
                <input 
                onChange={e => {
                  this.setState({ lw1val: e.target.value })

                }}
                value={this.state.lw1val}
                  onKeyPress={event => {

                    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
                      var inPutData = [
                        {
                          filterType: "is-equal-to",
                          value: event.target.value
                        }
                      ];

                      onChange(inPutData);
                    }
                  }}
                />
              ) : null}
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: @TonyAbrams That's not correct; the `value` of an input `onChange` target is the current value. https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/r8tLu0ah/2/

Comment: Is this the only code there is? This does what you'd expect: https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/r8tLu0ah/2/ so there's something else at play.

Comment: DaveNewton not working. TonyAbrams example please ?

Comment: @DaveNewton I updated the code

Comment: What is `onChange(inPutData);`?

Answer (score 3):

In input tag, specify which is your value:

```
<input value={this.state.lw1val} onChange= {event => this.setState({ lw1val: event.target.value })} />
```